# Custom JSF with Facelet

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, facelets, ajax4jsf, managed-bean

I have created a facelet page with one inputtext and datatable. This datatable will populate data from DB based on the input-text, We are going to use this facelet for look-up function in our application, and this will be used in more than one page or form. My question here is can we make that look-up facelet as a custom 'SearchButton' tag so that developers will add this SearchButton tag with two attributes (columns to populate and DB-tablename) to populate data.
Also note that my look-up facelet has been made with Primefaces UI component.

Please throw some light to develop this custom JSF component.

Rgds
Balaji

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it either a tag file or a composite component.

#### See also:

- [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen/6822269#6822269)

Comment: Thanks, sure will try this out. I have another question is there any component in primefaces or JSF to capture some-data (for e.g., in my lookup case developer should pass tablename and columnames to populate in grid) so that it will be bind to ManagedBean and this component wont get rendered in HTML. Please advise.

Comment: You can use `rendered` attribute of JSF component to specify whether it should be rendered or not.